# expectation $E[\bar{X}^2]$

Tags: expected-value

$Y = (\bar{X})^2$, where $\bar{X} = (X_1 + · · · + X_n)/n,$ to estimate $ E[X^2]$, where $ X, X_i $ are i.i.d. $ ∼ N(µ, σ^2)$.

How do we estimate the bias of the estimator Y here? The way I tried it is,
$E[(\bar{X}^2)] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^{n^2}  E[X_iX_j ]$

but I couldn't get to the solution with this, clearly, I am missing some property here, $= µ^2 +
{σ^2} / {n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just expand the square properly:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left( \bar{X}^2 \right) & = \mathbb{E  } \left( \frac{1}{n^2}  \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2 \right) \\ & = \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n X_i X_j \right) \\ & = \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{E} \left(X_1^2 \right) + \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i\neq j } \mathbb{E} \left(X_i X_j \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{n} \left(\sigma^2 + \mu^2 \right) + \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i\neq j} \mathbb{E} (X_i) \mathbb{E} (X_j) \\ & = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \frac{\mu^2}{n} + \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2} \mu^2 \\ & = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} + \mu^2
\end{align}

Can you see where we have used independence and identical distributions? Can you also tell where, if anywhere, we have used the assumption of a normal distribution?